# Refactor a stateful class

Tags: java, state, refactoring

I have a stateful class in java

```
class Container {
   int capacity;
   String name;
   
   public int getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
   }
   public void consumeContainer(int numberOfUnits) {
        this.capacity = this.capacity - numberOfUnits;
   }
}
```

I am looking for options to refactor this so I don't have to mutate the class everytime the container is consumed. Can the experts throw in ideas on how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Mutation refers to changing the internal state of the class. Try making use of final variables to prevent re-initialization or final methods to prevent overriding and final class to prevent class being inherited.

Comment: So, you want to make the class stateless/immutable? Do i understand correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make your class immutable, this is an option:

```
class ImmutableContainer {
    final int capacity;
    final String name;
               
    public ImmutableContainer(int capacity, String name) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.name = name;
    }
               
    public int getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    public ImmutableContainer consumeContainer(int numberOfUnits) {
        return new ImmutableContainer(this.capacity - numberOfUnits, name);
    }
}
```

Or, even simpler, as a record:

```
record ImmutableContainer(int capacity, String name) {

    public ImmutableContainer consumeContainer(int numberOfUnits) {
        return new ImmutableContainer(this.capacity - numberOfUnits, name);
    }
}
```